# How to enable Xcode Cloud code coverage report post build?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-cloud

I can't find any information on Xcode Cloud code coverage. At the end of the run, the menu only shows:

- Tests
- Logs
- Artifacts

What are the options here? Post-build script?

The workflow is setup with 2 actions:

- Build
- Test